# Background color not correctly applied

Tags: xaml, maui

I've got this custom control.

```cs
public class Panel : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CaptionProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached(nameof(Caption), typeof(string), typeof(Panel), "");

    public string Caption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Which is styled like this:

```xml
<Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="controls:Panel">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource PanelBorderStyle}" BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding BackgroundColor}" />
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource PanelCaptionLabelStyle}"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding Caption}" />
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="10,17,10,12" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When using the control `<control:Panel BackgroundColor="LimeGreen" />` the green color is applied to the whole background and not only the border. I thought the TemplateBinding on the ControlTemplate should prevent it from setting the BackgroundColor on the base ContentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limegreen color you see is not from the Border, but all from the `control:Panel`'s BackgroundColor. You don't set a `HeightRequest` or `WidthRequest` for the Border (or you may want to wrap the label with Border?).

So let's make a small demo to explain this senario,

We add another BindableProperty called `BorderColor` and set it a pink value. We also set the `HeightRequest` for Custom Control **Panel**,

```
<controls:Panel HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="LimeGreen" BorderColor="Pink" Caption="this is my text" />
```

In *Style*, bind the BackgroundColor of Border to **BorderColor**,

```
<Grid>
    <Border BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding BorderColor}" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Start" />
    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Caption}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
    <ContentPresenter/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the screenshot,

[image]

Here you can see clearly, the BackgroundColor of ContentView is Lime Green with the height of 100 and  the BackgroundColor for Border is Pink with the height of 50.

**Note**: Since you use [Grid Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-8.0). Be careful with the **overlap**.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the color to the `Stroke` property:

```xml
<Border Style="{StaticResource PanelBorderStyle}"
        Stroke="{TemplateBinding BackgroundColor}" />
```

Maybe the template should contain a value for `Stroke` instead of `BackgroundColor`, otherwise that's quite confusing.

See: [Microsoft / Learn / .NET / .NET MAUI /Border / Create a Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-8.0#create-a-border)